# Check if a project is of SharePoint Add-in type

Tags: sharepoint-online, development

How can I know if a project is of SharePoint Add-in type?

Is there any way through which I can verify the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SharePoint Add-in package is a file that has an ".app" extension, and every SharePoint Add-in includes an appmanifest.xml file. The appmanifest.xml tells SharePoint what it must know about the add-in and defines the add-in's most important properties.

More information about SharePoint Add-in, you can refer to:
[Explore the app manifest structure and the package of a SharePoint Add-in](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/explore-the-app-manifest-structure-and-the-package-of-a-sharepoint-add-in)